# Putting a php file in cake php

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, model-view-controller

I have a cake PHP project in which I need to put a php file in root folder like 'faq.php' and link it somewhere in the project. But as soon as I point to the url it redirects me to the index page. I don't want to dig deeper just want to add an static link. Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add any non-Cake content that needs to be accessed via the web browser in CakePHP you need to put it in the `webroot` folder as Cake's htaccess setup rewrites all other URLs. (If you're using the older CakePHP 2 the `webroot` folder is in `app`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it in the app/webroot directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can put any php and call it from wherever you want.

In your Templates Dir you will have an Element Dir - in there create  a FAQ dir and in the FAQ dir create a file called faq.ctp.

Then in the faq.ctp just drop in your php code, same as you would if writing in raw.

To call you can just call the element from whichever model you are in like so:

```
<?= $this->Element('FAQ/faq') ?>
```